# Need help for reinstall Windows 8.1 on Asus T100

Tags: tablet

**Background:**

I wiped everything before, **including the Recovery partition**, then I installed Win8.1 Pro.

**Issue:**

Today, the Windows suddenly show black screen when I was working, so I power it off and turn it on again, it shows the following screen:

(I downloaded this image from the Internet, the above instruction is the same but the bottom option is different. So I wiped the options and add the ONLY Only option "Press the WIndows key...." )
[image]

As there is no legacy mode/UEFI mode option in UEFI, some general method like using `Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool` to create USB boot key is not suitable for this situation, I can't access the Windows Boot Manager to let it boot from a legacy USB boot device just like what I did before to install Windows 8.1. I was looking for how to create a UEFI boot USB flash drive but it seems it only support Windows X64 and the UEFI bootloader of T100 is only support Windows X86. Please advice is there any other way to reinstall Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround:**

I found recently there is an up vote on this question, I believe someone is also facing this issue so I decide to share the solution, in short, **Install Windows 10**

**Why?:**

Windows 10 installation media is supporting X86 and X64 UEFI natively, so you don't have to mess around with different files like Windows 8.1.

There is tools behave like `Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool` to convert Windows Installation Media to USB, you can download it from here https://www.microsoft.com/zh-hk/software-download/windows10

**Ending Note:**

As Window 7 is not supported by ASUS T100 hardware, and I don't know how to install back the Windows 8.1, so Windows 10 is my last resort, as least I can get my operation system back online for working